# Searching for Java library to build an app that interacts with data

Tags: java, swt, visualization, data-visualization, data-analysis

I have a project where I should analyse data via cluster analysis. Basically the data should be visualised like this picture shows [image: Mockup]
Each dataset - for example let it be people - is one horizontal row, where vertical lines showing the attributes like sex, age, and so on.
Now if this data could be shown I also want to move the rows horizontal and also vertical a) via code and b) via drag & drop.

Do anybody know a good library for that?

Important

- Target is desktop application
- Expected datasets around 500
- Attributes for each data set around 60
- There is an app in Java/SWT already, so solutions in this direction would be preferred
- The OS is Win7 so C# or similar would be a stopgap
- I really like [d3.js](http://d3js.org), and would prefer a similar lock & feel (but in 3D)

If somebody has recommendations for a library which helps to analyze the data, please step forward too!

Comment: Are you willing to spend money on such a library or do you want a free one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [What is the best open-source java charting library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265777/what-is-the-best-open-source-java-charting-library-other-than-jfreechart) and [Libraries for pretty charts in SWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816/libraries-for-pretty-charts-in-swt) for more info.

I did used JFreeChart with SWT (2 years ago). The code is quite horrible (you have to write tons of code), but it works and is directly renderable with SWT components (no need of SWT_AWT bridge).

**EDIT**

When I thought about it again, I realized, that you can use the JavaScript library through `Browser` widget. It's quite heavyweight solution, but it might work..

Comment: Thank you. I like http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/ but it seams to miss 3D. 3D and interaction is really rare as it seams.

Comment: It's probably not that quite common usage.. So it's open source project, so you can write 3D bar support for that library ;]..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in d3 but it is a very involved process in which you need to deal with the ismoetric perspective and the rest.  It shouldn't be terribly complicated but it will not be an out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: I thought about that too. Is there an example of d3 in Java you know of?