# Jfreeshart support on SWT?

Tags: swt, rcp, timeserieschart

Hi I want to develop dynamic time series graph, (i.e time graphe which will updated automatically after few second) in SWT. I am able to do it using jFreechart in swing based application. Now I have shifted whole UI in eclipe RCP SWT. I have research ove web, I found that jfreechart not supported any longer on swt. is it true? SHould I drop jfreechart development on swt and find other altenative? what are other alternative for dynamic time series.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I wouldn't use JFreeChart in SWT, unless you are willing to either 1) fix bugs in it or 2) embed a Swing frame in your SWT GUI. There are several alternative libraries listed in [Libraries for pretty charts in SWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816/libraries-for-pretty-charts-in-swt)

Answer (score 1):

Dear @user2670032 there is an option to show jFreeChart in RCP but I am not sure this solution will be efficient in your case because in my case I need to show pie chart in RCP view only once.

1. Export chart as PNG image.
   `ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG('image-name', chart, 500, 300, info);`
2. Use SWT browser composite to show chart.
3. Use exported image path in HTML and set this HTML in browser composite.

This solution fulfills my need.

Answer (score 0):

Like any other Java Application coding, JFreechart chart application can be developed in SWT via adding jar in SWT Plugin development and coding
Add Chart in ViewPart in eclipse and that viewpart can be added to perspective.
Eclipse software can be developed